# R Shiny: Why do I need (Azure) SQL?

Tags: r, azure, shiny, azure-sql-database

I have 30GB of COVID risk from viral exposure data in a single flat CSV file. I have made an Rshiny app with filters that allow me to select a subset of these data and plot them. Eventually I would like a handful of people to use the Rshiny app in a secure environment outside of my organisation with password protection. Obviously I can't read then 30GB into memory so I have tried:

1. [Disk.frame](https://diskframe.com)
2. `sqlite`
3. Downsampling

But these are still super slow. I'm told I need `Azure SQL` and my data bottleneck problem will go away but that's about 10K per year. Is that my best option?

Please ask if I need to give more info.

**EDI: Some info about the data:**

Each row is a pretend passenger on public transport. Each column is some attribute about their journey: where they got on/off, the time they they got on/off, how close they were to an infectious person, whether they themselves were infectious and then the dose they received through breathing it or touching a surface. Then there are columns about the passenger loading, prevalence of then virus in the community and  others about the train itself. So these are a lot of **repetition** and no indexing. *I think that might be where the bottleneck is coming from.*

[image]

An example query would be:

1. Select passengers wearing masks &
2. Passengers that got on at FIN &
3. All passengers who wore masks &
4. Passengers where the train was 50% full &
5. Passengers that were on a train with bad ventilation.

Plot the dose they received.

Comment: There are many things that will ameliorate your size/speed problem, among them might be Azure SQL. But it is one of ***many*** options, including just about any/every DBMS out there. Whether you need a cloud deployment (i.e., *Azure*) depends on your deployment platform and other details. BTW: I've seen plenty of bottleneck on SQL Server as well, so it's not just *"throw SQL at it and all problems go away"*, there may need to be some architecting (depending on the data), including table indexing (clustered-vs-nonclustered, etc).

Comment: One interesting alternative would be Azure Synapse Analytics serverless database.  It's a pay-as-you go model which could work out cheaper.  Azure SQL serverless could be an option on the same basis.  Why not create a summary / aggregated file though which is much smaller?  Ppl don't need the line-level detail the whole time.

Comment: This question is likely to get a lot of *opinions*, so it may be closed as off-topic. A thought before then: `duckdb` allegedly is sqlite-like but faster. Other than that, asking about bottlenecks in those methods would be much more informed (and bring them back into "on-topic" territory) by looking at the schema and queries you're using. (Depending on the depth, [dba.se] might also be a good candidate, but again, it depends.)

Comment: After a moment of thought: please add the queries you're using, any indexes you've tried (in sqlite), and the structure of the data. I've had reasonable performance with larger SQLite dbs on shiny, where the difference was made in the indexing and query optimization. Ping me if you can add something :-)

Comment: @r2evans and wBob, thank you for such quick comments. I've added some spiel about the data and its structure, which hopefully shows how badly I've set it up.

Comment: 30GB of data with no indexing is almost certainly going to be a bottleneck. The indexes to create will depend heavily on the types of queries you are running, i.e., what fields are in your `WHERE` sql clause.

Comment: I don't see columns that would support *"train was 50% full"*, or per-passenger identification, or *"all passengers who wore masks"*, etc. I know it's a sample, I don't know the data well enough to be able to best inform any indexing. You may want to change some of your `chr` columns into integer enumerators, since int-comparison should be much faster than string comparison (e.g., `mask_wearing`, `exhaleType`, perhaps even `origin` and `destination`).

Comment: @r2evans you're right, I should have given col names.To get about 80 thousand records I would look for: percent==50 & prevalence == 0.001 & mask_wearing==Yes & fresh_flow<0.1 & is_infectious == 0

Comment: Column class is going to be a big player here. For instance, I'm inferring that `is_infection` is boolean or perhaps ternary, in which case it should be `logical` or `integer` (enums). Also, you should not be using `==` with floating point, I suggest one of two things: looking for a range of values (`percent between 45 and 55`) or binning them, such as done by `findInterval(percent, seq(0,100,by=10))`. Integer equality is much safer and faster than floating-point, and *that* bin can be indexed well.

Comment: @r2evans Makes sense. So at this stage we're still not just throwing SQL at it, but trying to optimise querying? Is there a way of changing then column type without reading the whole CSV into memory in R? I tried DB browser with an sqlite DB and it just doubled the size of the DB every time I changed the col type. Surely that's not right?

Comment: It should be manageable in a few ways. First, intermediate working size of the sqlite (or duckdb, don't forget) can be vacuumed down, so: import, do some work to recalibrate some columns into a new nearly-duplicate table (yes, double the size for a moment), remove the old table, then vacuum. This part may take some time, but you're hoping to optimize the "read" side of things, so time spent thinking about this and doing it will pay dividends later.

Comment: To be clear, yes, I'm recommending some form of SQL. I don't think Azure SQL is going to solve problems with zero or poor indexing, so I suggest you work on optimizing for the queries first, evaluate SQLite's (and duckdb's) performance, and then tweak the queries and indexing again. Realize that an index will increase the size of the db-file, sometimes substantially (depending on the index), so that's *normal* and generally acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

Azure SQL will meet the need for a database that will handle that data volume, and it will provide a secure environment in which to do that.

As for pricing, it doesn't need to cost $10K per year, unless you have very specific performance requirements. I just quoted an S2 database (50 DTUs, 250GB storage) for $89/month. If you want super-scalability, you can go serverless, and the same size database can support 2 vCores scaling on demand to 16 vCores for $113/month.

Now, does that mean you **have** to use Azure's SQL offering? No, but it could be a viable solution for you.